# Filter formula for multiple cell references

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

How can I make it so the formula on E2 reads values entered in any of the search cells and displays it as results, considering I have a button to clear all search boxes and users are instructed to only search one box at a time and to press the button if multiple boxes are filled?

[image][See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ntqy.png)

[Here's my editable Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKfh-XN8OUSQDQp_XB7gUX9RDlmZVrMN2ltznk7dU8c/edit?usp=sharing)

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(A2:C4; "where A = '"&B6&"' 
                       or B = '"&B7&"' 
                       or C = '"&B8&"'"; 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

> I'd like results to be shown only if the data users look for are in the same row.

```
=IFNA(QUERY(A2:C4; "where A = '"&B6&"' 
                      and B = '"&B7&"' 
                      and C = '"&B8&"'"; 0))
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(A2:C4; "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and "; 1; 
 IF(B6="";;"A = '"&B6&"'"); 
 IF(B7="";;"B = '"&B7&"'"); 
 IF(B8="";;"C = '"&B8&"'"))&""; 0))
```

Comment: Almost there, but it's only displaying results if all the 3 search fields are filled. What if I want to filter by COLUMN A and COLUMN B fields only (or B, C only or A, C only or A, B only), leaving one or more fields empty?

Comment: Exactly what I needed, @player0! But why doesn't it work with dates? Check the Spreadsheet again please, I updated it. Thanks.

Comment: dates are a bit different. see your sheet

Comment: Fantastic. Last question: How can I hide columns that countain blank cells based on what I look for? Please check the sheet. BTW I've already voted up and chose yours as the best answer.

Comment: @iamthe202 see your sheet. that's the best you can do. otherwise, you would need to use script to hide empty columns

Comment: wow. you're good. it's ok this way. how hard would it be for me to make it work for, say, 50 new "QTY." columns? can you give me an example of what I'd have to add in the function and where, consecutively? i want to learn how to walk by myself from what you gave me so I won't bother you no more. thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need to change a range and it should all work well

Comment: I get #VALUE when I use this final formula on my spreadsheet. It says Column A doesn't exist, and even if I rename "A" to "Col1", it then says Column S doesn't exist, then replacing "S" by "Col19", it says Col19 doesn't exist. Check image: imgur dot com slash a6D5Gtx / Check function: pastebin dot com slash pjs4Pwt6

Comment: formula should be: https://pastebin.com/raw/egMAyg4d all in Col references because  you do not use direct range but instead your range is wrapped in to_text() formula. also when using to_text() you dont have to use date parameter in query syntax because datevalue gets converted to text string via to_text formula

Comment: I see. It's still giving the same error though. I pasted your formula. See image https://i.imgur.com/lihzSYW.png

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I just sent you an e-mail with the link, since it has sensitive data; I allowed your e-mail (alternative400@gmail.com) to edit the copy. My wish is to add S:DP.

Comment: replacing Col19 to Col2 didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine conditions via `+` and `*`

```
=IFNA(
  FILTER(A2:C4;(A2:A4=B6)+(B2:B4=B7)+(C2:C4=B8));
  "Enter the data for the request"
)
```

[image]